# Parameters for the Diffie-Hellman algorithm

Tags: javascript, cryptography

Which parameters are recommended to use in Diffie-Hellman algorithm? This moment I have some like this :

Alice :

```
(shared) p value = 443 
(shared) g value = 4
(secret) a value =  392
(public key) A = 203
```

Bob:

```
(shared) p value = 443
(shared) g value = 4
(secret) b value =  356
(public key) B = 47
```

After exchange A and B public keys Alice and Bob can calculate Private Keys like this :

> Alice Private Key : K= 47^392 MOD 443 = 89
>
> Bob Private Key : K= 203^356 MOD 443 = 89

I think these public and private keys are to short now, is'nt ? But which length must been for p,g,a,A parameters instead ?

Comment: [keylengths](https://www.keylength.com/).

Comment: @JamesKPolk As I can see, on the link provided only public/private key strength recommendation(256bit) but no length. And whats about `p,g,a` parameters ?